# How to convert my RelativeLayout from XML to dynamically, programmatically produced Layout?

Tags: android, android-layout

SOLVED - The ID of a View-Element should not be set to 0 !!!

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >


        <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button 1"/>

    <EditText
         android:id="@+id/editText1"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"                  
         android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Button1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button 2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Button1"/>

    <EditText
         android:id="@+id/editText2"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
         android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Button2"/> 

        <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button 2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Button2"/>

    <EditText
         android:id="@+id/editText3"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
         android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Button3"/> 

</RelativeLayout>
```

Now that is my Code in the Activity, i tried to to exactly what i did in the xml, but the items are displayed completely different:

```
  public class MainActivity extends Activity { 

    private RelativeLayout relativeLayout;
    public RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams;

     @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);


            layoutParams = new  RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);           

            //button 1
            Button button1 = new Button(this);
            button1.setText("Button 1");
            button1.setId(0);           
            relativeLayout.addView(button1);            

            //editText1
            EditText editText1 = new EditText(this);
            editText1.setId(1);
            layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, 0);
            relativeLayout.addView(editText1, layoutParams);            
            layoutParams = new  RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);               

            // button2
            Button button2 = new Button(this);
            button2.setText("Button 2");
            button2.setId(2);
            layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, 0);
            relativeLayout.addView(button2, layoutParams);
            layoutParams = new  RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

            //editText2
            EditText editText2 = new EditText(this);
            editText2.setId(3);
            layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, 1);
            layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, 2);
            relativeLayout.addView(editText2, layoutParams);
            layoutParams = new  RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);


            this.setContentView(relativeLayout);            

        }

}
```

SOLVED:
The main issue is, that an id of 0 for a view-element is not allowed...erm yea, beginner's mistake, i know...
THANK you anyone for helping on this question! SOLVED!!!

Comment: why do you want to avoid xml layouts ?

Comment: can we see screenshots to understand what do you mean by "completely different" ?

Answer (score 4):

Try [this](http://www.xmltojava.com/)! It converts xml to java code. However, I am not quite sure if you really need it in this case...

Answer (score 0):

You're doing all these backwards

```
relativeLayout.addView(button2, layoutParams);
layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,           ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

Should be

```
layoutParams = new  RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
button2.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
relativeLayout.addView(button2);
```

You may need to do more to get it the way you want, but why are you wanting to do this? If it works why change it?

Comment: No im Doing before every one a new one.The first one comes before the first button. Because there are new settings in every stept...

Answer (score 0):

you have already added the buttons to the xml file why are you creating dynamic buttons instead inflate the view if you want to add the layout dynamically also when you dynamically add the buttons to the relative layout you must call addRule function to place them at right place

just create objects of button and edittext refer the as you have refere your relative layout

```
relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);
```

and use them.

Edit----

For that you must remove buttons from the xml layout and then create the buttons like you are doing it's prefect just one thing like this here

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/Button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button 1"/>

    <EditText
         android:id="@+id/editText1"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"                  
         **android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Button1"** />
```

to place this editText you must use addRule() function

```
EditText editText1 = new EditText(this);
            editText1.setId(1);
            layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, 0);
            relativeLayout.addView(editText1, layoutParams);            
            layoutParams = new  RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);    

layoutParams .addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, 0);
```

where 0 is your button's id also set the layout params too to the layout like

```
editText.setLayoutParams(layoutParams );
```

Comment: Look at my code, that is exactly what i did, and it does not work.

Comment: With the xml: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B8g5mxR-PqMbV1VuOFJEVmlQakE/edit?usp=sharing

without the xml: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B8g5mxR-PqMbQVZaZlphbEE2TEk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: this is because you haven't used the addRule function that's what I have mentioned in my answer when you create layout dynamically relative layout places every component at top-left you have to assign positions

Comment: layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, 0);  that is copy pasted from my code above. I used the addRule Function...

Comment: i just didnt use it for the first item, because that one doesnt need to be layouted...